# Android Notification Icon not showing in letv

Tags: android, notifications, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am setting notification icon both small and large one but it is showing default app icon which i have not set. So please help me on this. Thank you..

Here is the code:

```
 android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
                .setLargeIcon(artwork)
                .setContentIntent(clickIntent)
                .setContentTitle(getTrackName())
                .setContentText(text)
                .setWhen(mNotificationPostTime)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_skip_previous_white_36dp,
                        "",
                        retrievePlaybackAction(PREVIOUS_ACTION))
                .addAction(playButtonResId, "",
                        retrievePlaybackAction(TOGGLEPAUSE_ACTION))
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_skip_next_white_36dp,
                        "",
                        retrievePlaybackAction(NEXT_ACTION));
```

Here is snapshot of letv(Which is having problem[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GY5YC.png)):

Here is snapshot of Genymotion Emulator(Expected output):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WonjI.png)

Both are running on android 6.0(Api level 23)

Comment: As a temporary fix, try changing the target version to 20 in manifest and let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

Add this meta data in your manifest file and then you can change your default notification icon.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_ic_notification" />
```